# Is there any way to notify IE about changes done in registry via code?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, registry, notifications

I have done changes in registry (proxy settings) via Windows programming code.

I have to restart (reopen) Internet Explorer each time I run the code to make those changes take effect.

Is there any API in Windows programming through which I can notify Internet Explorer or Windows that changes are made to the registry and there will not be any need to reopen Internet Explorer to make those changes take effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change Internet Explorer 7 Proxy Setting without Restarting Internet Explorer
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Change_IE7_Proxy_Setting.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with Shell apis (FAQ).
See on Win32 api group 
news://nntp.aioe.org/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it successfully with API `InternetSetOption`.

Comment: InternetSetOption(0, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, 0, 0);
InternetSetOption(0, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, 0, 0);